The rule for opening empty cells in the game Minesweeper in Prolog does not work
I have developed a minesweeper game in Prolog language. I am a student and this is my project on the subject of AI. I created a knowledge base, and the rules by which the game should be played. The rule for opening cells displays unnecessary and incorrect data.
Here is the knowledge base:
:- dynamic(cell/4).
:- discontiguous game_over/0.


field_size(5, 4).
mine_count(3).


mine(2, 1).
mine(3, 3).
mine(5, 2).


cell(1, 1, open, 1).
cell(1, 2, closed, _).
cell(1, 3, closed, _).
cell(1, 4, closed, _).


cell(2, 1, closed, _).
cell(2, 2, closed, _).
cell(2, 3, open, 1).
cell(2, 4, closed, _).


cell(3, 1, open, 1).
cell(3, 2, open, 2).
cell(3, 3, closed, _).
cell(3, 4, closed, _).


cell(4, 1, closed, _).
cell(4, 2, closed, _).
cell(4, 3, open, 2).
cell(4, 4, closed, _).


cell(5, 1, closed, _).
cell(5, 2, closed, _).
cell(5, 3, closed, _).
cell(5, 4, closed, _).


I have a rule that should open empty neighboring cells if the cell the player clicked on was empty. For example, a player clicks on a cell, it turns out to be empty, then all neighboring cells that are empty should open recursively until they reach cells that have a number, the last cells that have a number should open, then the rule breaks out of recursiveness.
A rule that opens empty cells recursively is open_adjacent(X, Y). This rule also affects rules such as adjacent(X, Y, X1, Y1) and count_mines(X, Y, Count). These rules help you check if a cell is empty and find neighbors.
adjacent(X, Y, X1, Y1) :-
   field_size(MaxX, MaxY),
   (X1 is X + 1, Y1 is Y + 1;
    X1 is X + 1, Y1 is Y - 1;
    X1 is X + 1, Y1 is Y;
    X1 is X - 1, Y1 is Y + 1;
    X1 is X - 1, Y1 is Y - 1;
    X1 is X - 1, Y1 is Y;
    X1 is X, Y1 is Y + 1;
    X1 is X, Y1 is Y - 1
   ),
   X > 0, X1 > 0, Y > 0, Y1 > 0,
   X =< MaxX, X1 =< MaxX, Y =< MaxY, Y1 =< MaxY,
   cell(X, Y, _, _),
   cell(X1, Y1, _, _),
   abs(X - X1) =< 1,
   abs(Y - Y1) =< 1,
   abs(X - X1) + abs(Y - Y1) \= 0.


count_mines(X, Y, Count) :-
   findall(1, (adjacent(X, Y, AdjX, AdjY), mine(AdjX, AdjY)), Mines),
   length(Mines, Count).


open_cell(X, Y) :-
   cell(X, Y, closed, _),
   mine(X, Y),
   retract(cell(X, Y, closed, _)),
   assert(cell(X, Y, open, _)),
   write('Вы попали на мину!'), nl,
   !,
   game_over.


open_cell(X, Y) :-
   cell(X, Y, closed, _),
   count_mines(X, Y, Count),
   (Count > 0 ->
       retract(cell(X, Y, closed, _)),
       assert(cell(X, Y, open, Count)),
       write('open cell > 0\n')
       ;
       retract(cell(X, Y, closed, _)),
       assert(cell(X, Y, open, 0)),
       write('open cell = 0\n'),
       open_adjacent(X, Y)
   ),
   game_over.  


open_adjacent(X, Y) :-
   adjacent(X, Y, AdjX, AdjY), 
   (cell(AdjX, AdjY, closed, _) -> (
       count_mines(AdjX, AdjY, Count),  
       (Count = 0 ->  
           retract(cell(AdjX, AdjY, closed, _)), 
           assert(cell(AdjX, AdjY, open, 0)),  
           write('open cell: ('), write(AdjX), write(', '), write(AdjY), write('), adjacent mines: '), writeln(Count),
           open_adjacent(AdjX, AdjY),  
           game_over  
        ;   
           retract(cell(AdjX, AdjY, closed, _)),
           assert(cell(AdjX, AdjY, open, Count)),
           write('open cell:  ('), write(AdjX), write(', '), write(AdjY), write('), adjacent mines: '), writeln(Count)
       ));
   write('Cell was open:('), write(AdjX), write(', '), write(AdjY), write(')')).

This is my program output. I know that cell (1, 4) is empty and next to it there is another empty one, so I try to open them recursively.
?- open_adjacent(1, 4).
The cage was opened: (2, 3)
true ;
Open cell: (2, 4), adjacent mines: 1
true ;
Open cell: (1, 3), adjacent mines: 0
Cell was open: (2, 4)Cell was open: (2, 2), adjacent mines: 2
Cell was open: (2, 3)Cell was open: (1, 4), adjacent mines: 0
Cell was open: (2, 3)Cell was open: (2, 4)Cage was open: (1, 3)Cell was open: (1, 2), adjacent mines: 1

This is my field. Where there are large circles these are mines, where there are zeros these are empty cells.

This output is very strange because for some reason extra cells are opened and also the cells are opened several times:
Cell was open: (2, 4)Cell was open: (2, 2), adjacent mines: 2
Cell was open: (2, 3)Cell was open: (1, 4), adjacent mines: 0
Cell was open: (2, 3)Cell was open: (2, 4)Cage was open: (1, 3)Cell was open: (1, 2), adjacent mines: 1

I checked my code and I don’t understand where the error could have occurred, what is the output?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

A guess, (Count > 0 -> (retract assert write) ; (retract assert write, open_adjacent))  add those extra parens around the 'blocks'.  I wonder if it's parsing (if Count>0 retract), assert, write OR retract, assert, write and then backtracking around the ;.

https://github.com/triska/clpb in Prolog would be great to use for Minesweeper.
